# Создайте копию бинарного дерева поиска и отобразите его в TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms

Необходимо создать двоичное дерево поиска, а затем скопировать дерево и отобразить в TreeView.
 метод создания дерева

```
public DTreeNode Created(DTreeNode root,char temp, int nums) //temp - information field.nums - key
   {
        if (root == null)
        {
            root = new DTreeNode(temp, nums);
            root.Left = null;
            root.Right = null;
        }
        else
        {
            if (nums < root.Key)
            {
                root.Left = Created(root.Left, temp, nums);
            }
            else
            {
                root.Right = Created(root.Right, temp, nums);
            }
        }
        return root;
    }
```

Методы вывода дерева в TreeView

```
public void Show(TreeView tree, DTreeNode root)
    {
        tree.Nodes.Clear();
        if (root != null)
        {
            tree.Nodes.Add(root.Info + "  (" + root.Key + ")");
            KLP(tree.Nodes[0], root.Left);
            KLP(tree.Nodes[0], root.Right);
        }
    }
    public void KLP(TreeNode node, DTreeNode place)
    {
        if (place != null)
        {
            TreeNode branch = node.Nodes.Add(place.Info + "  (" + place.Key + ")");
            KLP(branch, place.Left);
            KLP(branch, place.Right);
        }
    }
```

Но как скопировать двоичное дерево поиска и отобразить его в TreeView, я не знаю. Пожалуйста, помогите. Я не могу сделать это уже 5 дней. Вся работа выполняется в Windows Forms.

Comment: Будьте более конкретны, что именно у вас не получается?

Answer (score 0):

У вас не BST, а просто Tree, т. к. BST – это значение + left node + right node. Вашу модель я буду реализовывать через интерфейс узлов:

```
public interface IBinaryTreeNode<T> : ICollection<T>
{
    IBinaryTreeNode<T> Root { get; }
    IBinaryTreeNode<T>? Parent { get; }
    [MaybeNull, AllowNull] // может возвращать/получать null на входе/выходе
    T Value { get; set; }
    IBinaryTreeNode<T>? Left { get; }
    IBinaryTreeNode<T>? Right { get; }

    void Remove(); // удаляет этот узел из дерева
    int ComputeTotalCount(); // вычисляет кол-во *всех* дочерних узлов данного узла
    // ... // прочие методы (не играют важной роли)
}
```

Такая модель – это модель BST. Если вы не подразумевали подобный этому BST, то смысл не меняется:

*Рекурсивный метод*

```
// для BST
public void InitTreeView(TreeNode tree, IBinaryTreeNode<T> node)
{
    // checks

    tree.Text = node.Value.ToString(); // инициализируем значение данного узла
    tree.Nodes.Clear(); // очищаем чтобы инициализация не "стакалась"

    // левый узел
    var left = new TreeNode();
    InitTreeView(left, node.Left);
    tree.Nodes.Add(left);

    // правый узел
    var right = new TreeNode();
    InitTreeView(right, node.Right);
    tree.Nodes.Add(right);
}
// для Tree
public void InitTreeView(TreeNode tree, ITreeNode<T> node) // `ITreeNode<T>` - интерфейс вашего типа узлов
{
    // checks

    tree.Text = node.Value.ToString();
    tree.Nodes.Clear();

    foreach (var child in node.Children)
    {
        var _child = new TreeNode();
        InitTreeView(_child, child);
        tree.Nodes.Add(_child);
    }
}
```

Comment: у меня одного не подсвечивается синтаксис?

Comment: Да, синтаксис не подсвечивался. Указание языка, наоборот, мешало.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov спасибо, что исправили